# Is it possible to show an icon before the title in the header of a Modern Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to put my own icon in before the title in the header of a modern sharepoint site?
Like this example:

[image]

I know you can add an emoticon by pressing Windows key + period. But can this be done with my own icon OR perhaps is there a way to put my own icons in the emoticons depository so that i can choose my own icon by pressing win key + period ?

Gr. Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you question as a Site Owner/Author of the site whether it's available out of the box, I believe there's no way to do that.

But as a developer, there (probably) ways to customize via SharePoint Framework (SPFx) component that's built through **Application Customizer**, that will hijack the placeholder of the title and put the well-known image URL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions